# React table - how to merge tables for specific column and cell value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

This is 2 tables that I've created.
[image]

and it's its data

```
  const callData = [
    { id: 1, type: "call", volume: 50000, strike: 3000 },
    { id: 2, type: "call", volume: 30000, strike: 5000 },
    { id: 3, type: "call", volume: 20000, strike: 7000 }
  ];

  const putData = [
    { id: 1, type: "put", volume: 50000, strike: 3000 },
    { id: 2, type: "put", volume: 10000, strike: 5000 },
    { id: 3, type: "put", volume: 7000, strike: 7000 }
  ];
```

If you click the row, it will print something like

```
  const rowOnClick = (row) => {
    let obj = row.values;
    console.log(`clicked ${obj.type} for Strike ${obj.strike}`);
  };

// log "clicked call for Strike 3000"
```

Now I want to merge these 2 tables together.
The one single table will be like
[image]

If I click the row in red box, it should print `clicked call for Strike xxx`.
If I click the row in green box, it should print `clicked put for Strike xxx`.

For example, if I click the row in red box for `strike 5000`, it prints `clicked call for Strike 5000`

How can I do it?

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-easley-v6h8p?file=/src/App.js:0-2789

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useTable } from "react-table";

const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;

  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;

      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
`;

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });

  const rowOnClick = (row) => {
    let obj = row.values;
    console.log(`clicked ${obj.type} for Strike ${obj.strike}`);
  };

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()} onClick={() => {}}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr
              {...row.getRowProps()}
              onClick={() => {
                rowOnClick(row);
              }}
            >
              {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Info",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "Type",
            accessor: "type"
          },
          {
            Header: "Volume",
            accessor: "volume"
          },
          {
            Header: "Strike",
            accessor: "strike"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  // got below data from async request
  const callData = [
    { id: 1, type: "call", volume: 50000, strike: 3000 },
    { id: 2, type: "call", volume: 30000, strike: 5000 },
    { id: 3, type: "call", volume: 20000, strike: 7000 }
  ];

  const putData = [
    { id: 1, type: "put", volume: 50000, strike: 3000 },
    { id: 2, type: "put", volume: 10000, strike: 5000 },
    { id: 3, type: "put", volume: 7000, strike: 7000 }
  ];

  return (
    <Styles>
      <Table columns={columns} data={callData} />
      <Table columns={columns} data={putData} />
    </Styles>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Sorry, is there a question here? what is the issue you're having?

Comment: @John Ruddell I want to know how to merge 2 tables

Comment: tables in html dont merge, they are pretty opinionated. You could do some hacky stuff with absolute positioning to get the tables to line up, but maybe writing a data converter to merge this data together and render one table would be a better approach

Comment: @CCCC I've implemented an example of your requirement here : https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-scott-kvhhw . could  you pelase check it out does it solve your problem or not

Comment: @Saeed Shamloo yes! please post the answer so that I can accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge your data into one object and render juse one table. Also instaed of using `onClick` on the `tr` element, you can handle your requirement by using `onClick` on the `td` elements and decide what data should be send to `rowOnClick` method, on the callback of `td`'s onClick.like this:

```
 {rows.map((row, i) => {
      prepareRow(row);
      return (
        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
          {row.cells.map((cell) => {
            ...
            return <td  {...cell.getCellProps()} 
            onClick={ column === 'strike' ? undefined : ()=> rowOnClick({...})}>
              {cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
          })}
        </tr>
      );
    })}
```

I implemented an example [here on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-scott-kvhhw) you can check it out.